# Translation of "in a pickle" and related phrases

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, modismos

In English there are several idioms or phrases that describe being in the midst of a very difficult situation:

- in a pickle
- in a quandary
- in a predicament
- in between a rock and a hard place

How would the meaning of these English phrases be best translated to Spanish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some options:

> en un aprieto
>
> en un apuro
>
> en una situación comprometida
>
> entre la espada y la pared (for the last one)

I wouldn't know for sure how the nuances of these expressions correspond to the one in yours (since I'm not that familiar with them). However, the last ones in your list and mine clearly correspond.

Another option (which might correspond nicely to the "dilemma" aspect) is

> en una encrucijada

Comment: As a side comment, here in Uruguay a very common expression between young people nowadays is "estoy en el horno" ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would "recast" the English expression as "cornered." The Spanish equivalent would then be **arrinconado**.